# Regex for htaccess greater than 10

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I'm not very good at regular expressions...
The only thing I want to achieve is to match in the htaccess when the page number is greater than 10.
I've tried the following regular expression:

```
^(\d\d\d*)$
```

but it matches 10, because it's the first two-digit number.

Any ideas?
Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew it matches 009 too (which I am not sure if is a valid scenario in htaccess?)

Comment: Yes, that is my old suggestion. See my answer below with a fixed pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
^(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,})$
```

If you need to allow any amount of leading zeros, you may use

```
^0*(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,})$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LPGsKl/2) and the [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A1%5B1-9%5D%7C%5B2-9%5D%5Cd%7C%5B1-9%5D%5Cd%7B2%2C%7D)%24):

[image]

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:1[1-9]|[2-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,})`:

  - `1[1-9]` - `11` to `19`
  - `|` - or
  - `[2-9]\d|` - `20` to `99`, or
  - `[1-9]\d{2,}` - `100` and more
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: I mean, this matches `001` instead of rejecting it, even with the 0* after the ^

Comment: @totok Ok, that was due to `\d{3}`. I assumed the numbers never start with leading zeros. I have changed the pattern to cancel out those matches.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The first option works perfectly for my needs! Thank you very much for the detailed explanation!

Answer (score 0):

`^(1[1-9]|[2-9]+\d+|1\d\d+)$`

You may test it in https://regex101.com (it has great explanation for each step even)

I used scenarios: 9, 10, 11, 20, 009, 09, 300, 4445, 100

Explanation: the OR (|) operator separates 3 regex expressions:

- 1[1-9] - exactly 2 digits, 11 to 19
- [2-9]+\d+   Here:

  - [2-9]+ means 1 or more digits in range 2-9
  - \d+ - any digit 1 or more occurrence
- 1\d\d+ - 3 and more digit numbers starting with digit 1

Comment: @user13763372 am glad u found your answer